# Get selected tag from react tag autocomplete component within a form to submit…

Tags: reactjs

The problem is in the question,
How to Get selected tags from react tag autocomplete component in a form which contains other input field to submit all of them at least. An example of the form

```
<form action=””>
  <input type="text" name="toto" />
  <ReactTagComponent />
  <input type="text" name="titi" />
  <button type="text">Save</button>
 </form>
```

I want to get selected from react-tag-autocomplete Component (Child component) to Parent component which have the form for submitting …
Thanks